# How can I temporarily replace 'and' with 'or' when using `\cref` command?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref, ref, tags

The code below generates correct output. However, I would like to know how I can temporarily replace every instance of 'and' with 'or' just for specific instances of `\cref` usage. I included `xcolor` and `hyperref` on purpose because I want the solution to be compatible with hyper links.

```
 \documentclass[reqno]{amsart}


\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}



\crefformat{equation}{Eq. #2(#1)#3}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{Eqs. #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{Eqs. #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}{, #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}{Eqs. #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{, #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}

\begin{document}


    \begin{align}
        e &= m c^{2}
        \label{eq1}
        \\
        r &= \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}
        \label{eq2}
        \\
        R_{eq} &= \left( \frac{1}{R_{1}} + \frac{1}{R_{2}} \right)^{-1}
        \label{eq3}
        \\
        V &= R I
        \label{eq4}
        \\
        S &= V I^{*}
        \label{eq5}
        \\
        P &= V I \cos(\theta)
        \label{eq6}
        \\
        Q &= V I \cos(\theta)
        \label{eq7}
    \end{align}

    \cref{eq1,eq3}

    \cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq6,eq7}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the conjunction depending on a macro:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{Eq. #2(#1)#3}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{Eqs. #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
\crefmultiformat{equation}
  {Eqs. #2(#1)#3}
  { \andor\  #2(#1)#3}
  {, #2(#1)#3}
  { \andor\ #2(#1)#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}
  {Eqs. #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
  { and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
  {, #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
  { and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
\newcommand{\andor}{and}
\newcommand{\crefor}[1]{\begingroup\renewcommand{\andor}{or}\cref{#1}\endgroup}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
e &= m c^{2}
\label{eq1}
\\
r &= \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}
\label{eq2}
\\
R_{eq} &= \left( \frac{1}{R_{1}} + \frac{1}{R_{2}} \right)^{-1}
\label{eq3}
\\
V &= R I
\label{eq4}
\\
S &= V I^{*}
\label{eq5}
\\
P &= V I \cos(\theta)
\label{eq6}
\\
Q &= V I \cos(\theta)
\label{eq7}
\end{align}

\cref{eq1,eq3}

\cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq6,eq7}

\crefor{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq6,eq7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but what about using the `\Cref` functionality to define something different? For example:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}


\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}



\crefformat{equation}{Eq. #2(#1)#3}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{Eqs. #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{Eqs. #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}{, #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{Eqs. #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}{, #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}
\Crefmultiformat{equation}{Eqs. #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}{, #2(#1)#3}{ or #2(#1)#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}{Eqs. #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{, #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}

\begin{document}


    \begin{align}
    e &= m c^{2}
    \label{eq1}
    \\
    r &= \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}
    \label{eq2}
    \\
    R_{eq} &= \left( \frac{1}{R_{1}} + \frac{1}{R_{2}} \right)^{-1}
    \label{eq3}
    \\
    V &= R I
    \label{eq4}
    \\
    S &= V I^{*}
    \label{eq5}
    \\
    P &= V I \cos(\theta)
    \label{eq6}
    \\
    Q &= V I \cos(\theta)
    \label{eq7}
    \end{align}

    \cref{eq1,eq3}

    \cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq6,eq7}

    \Cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq6,eq7}

\end{document}
```

[image]